# Difference between import and scripts in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

Due to a dependency I have to import React in my Angular application. When I add it in my angular.json scripts tag, it works out well. An example of this can be found here: https://github.com/arnvanhoutte/ng-gutenberg/blob/master/angular.json

However if I do this, react will be included everywhere in my app. I don't really want this, as it creates a lot of overhead. Ideally I would just like to include react in the component that needs this dependency. I thought that just adding `import 'react'` and `import 'react-dom'` would do the trick. Sadly when I do that I get a lot of errors showing that react is not defined. This got me thinking a bit and I am very surprised by this. What is the difference between an import statement and just adding it in my build? How come it is not working with an import?

Comment: Did you try `import * as react from 'react'`?

Comment: I did. Still the same error